# Automation on MessageSession End

Tags: trigger, messagingsession

Is there a way to fire any automation when a MessageSession record's status is changed to "Ended", or in other words when the user clicks end chat?

I have got a MessageSession trigger that I can see is firing on update via the developer console's debug logs, but no debug log is created when end chat is clicked. Also tried a process builder but same issue, doesn't fire.

Several use cases, parenting files to the correct record (Lead and/or Case) and saving the conversation elsewhere etc.

If relevant I can see a rest call to the below in the Chrome network console when clicking end chat:

```
salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Conversational/ConversationEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Some observations for others in the future:

1. Any image/file upload is done via the Automated Process User
2. End Chat does not set the MessagingSession Status to Ended, the
   MessagingSession trigger does **not** fire here
3. Closing the MessagingSession tab does change the status Ended, and the MessagingSession trigger **fires**
4. For point 3, the trigger runs as the automated process user!

Comment: I so much appreciate it when a dev is stuck for a while, then figures it out, then posts a self-answered question. Will save others endless hours.